# UWP: Fastest way to create an InMemoryRandomAccessStream from a byte array

Tags: c#, performance, uwp, stream

I need to create an InMemoryRandomAccessStream from a byte[] in the fastest way possible.

I came out with this method

```
private static async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> GetStreamAsync(byte[] bytes)
{
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
    stream.Seek(0);
    return stream;
}
```

but unfortunately it takes like 8 milliseconds, and for our purpose it is way too much.

Is there a faster (and maybe synchronous) way to achieve the same purpose?

I am looking for a time around 1 millisecond or less.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you need it, and why do you need it to be so fast? Can you deal with an `IRandomAccessStream`? Then perhaps write your own wrapper around a byte array, implementing that interface.

Comment: I need an IRandomAccessStream to pass to CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync() to load an image into a SpriteVisual using Win2D api.

Answer (score 0):

> I need an IRandomAccessStream to pass to CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync() to load an image into a SpriteVisual using Win2D api.

For your comment, Maybe the `IRandomAccessStream` is really what you needed, not `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`.

Here is the other way to get the IAccessRandomStream from byte array:

```cs
private IRandomAccessStream GetStreamAsync(byte[] bytes)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    var stream = ms.AsRandomAccessStream();
    stream.Seek(0);
    return stream;
}
```

This way is faster than the original method.

However, the speed of image loading has many influencing factors, we can only try to improve it.

I hope this can help you.